# Is the Hadith about "the prophet sucking on the tongue" true?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

I've just came across a comment from a (probably Christian)

> I recently stumbled upon a Hadith that said this too!
>
> Musnad Ahmad 16245—[Mua’wiya said]: I saw the prophet sucking on the tongue or the lips of Al-Hassan son of Ali, may the prayers of Allah be upon him. For no tongue or lips that the prophet sucked on will be tormented (by hell fire)

Which I can't even believe. This is disgusting and I do believe this is not real.  So I searched for a while. What I came across is

> ولن يعذب لسان او شفتان مصهما رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم

Referenced from musnad imam ahmad. v: 4. p: 91 — kanz-ul haqaiq. p: 62

And made a few more search and found the following Arabic websites discussing this issue

[http://www.hurras.org](http://www.hurras.org/vb/showthread.php?t=34&s=f4f87d6889c8e10bb919f5735dc3b785)

[http://aljame3.net](http://aljame3.net/ib/index.php?s=3ac76b90ccf7b730230b256d8436dfee&showtopic=7144&st=0&p=33423&)

However, I have no Arabic background to understand them. Can anyone shed some light about this issue?

Comment: Google translate can translate paragraphs, Allah knows best what happened is better to say as it appears people have different opinions on this therefore i would not take it into consideration my self as i do not know truly what has happened and these are all assumptions, only God knows the past and the future as god is the all knowing

Comment: WE have enough knowledge of how to perform our worships that's what we are concerned about

Comment: Agreed. We are responsible of what is ordered in Qur'an and sunnahs of the prophet Muhammad (sallallahu alaihi wasallam). However, if an atheist or christian comes to a Muslim with these kind of questions, he need to be capable of answering to them. That's the issue I'm concerning about.

Comment: I understand, but not every hadeeth is authentic, the Arabic sites you referred to mentions that this is a made up incident by the enemies of Islam and others say it truly happened but not in the same sense you mentioned, which explains why i repeatably said Allah knows best.

Comment: Whether the hadith mentioned is authentic or not, I don't see why that action should be labeled as "disgusting". Back in my home country it's a wide spread custom that parents and grandparents chew food and give it to infants directly from their mouths (just like how birds do).

Comment: @shoerat I should note that it's disgusting or not is kind of cultural.

Comment: @ctr had it been some movie and 2 Hollywood celebrities engaging in sucking each others tongue, it wouldn't have been disgusting, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two commonly used narrations about the said matter.

First is the one you've mentioned in *Musnad Ahmed*.

Second is from *[al-Adab al-Mufrad](http://sunnah.com/urn/2311800)* of al-Bukhari.

Both of these reports are not authentic.

The *sanad* for the first one is:

> حَدَّثَنَا هَاشِمُ بْنُ الْقَاسِمِ، حَدَّثَنَا حَرِيزٌ، عَنْ عَبْدِ
>   الرَّحْمَنِ ابْنِ أَبِي عَوْفٍ الْجُرَشِيِّ، عَنْ مُعَاوِيَةَ، قَالَ:
>   رَأَيْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ

Abdul Rahman bin Abi Awf is unknown [said by Abul Hasan al-Qatan al-Fasi] and wasn't known to be a narrator of *hadith*.

The second narrations *sanad* is:

> حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ الْمُنْذِرِ قَالَ‏:‏ حَدَّثَنِي ابْنُ
>   أَبِي فُدَيْكٍ قَالَ‏:‏ حَدَّثَنِي هِشَامُ بْنُ سَعْدٍ، عَنْ نُعَيْمِ
>   بْنِ الْمُجْمِرِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ

Hisham bin Saed is weak as was said by Yahya bin Maen, and weakened by an-Nasai.

Hence, both reports have problems.

It should be noted that Arabs used to suck on their children's tongues to lower the child's thirst (*ash-Shifa* of Qadhi Iyad).

Comment: The 2nd narration is grade hasan. That does not mean inauthentic.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is indeed so interesting. I found some similar matter(s) with some or even much differences. In truth, as a view of Shia and based on what I found:

The apostle of Allah (peace be upon him and his family) put his tongue in Imam Hassan’s mouth (when Hassan was a newborn), then Imam Hassan sucked it. Or as another issue, it is narrated that: (briefly)

> Someday Imam Hassan was (so) thirsty, he asked his grandfather some
> water with much importunity; well, there was no water; afterwards The
> Prophet (pbuh) put his tongue in Hassan’s mouth, then he became
> completely satisfied (for his thirst). / Imam Hassan (a.s.) always was
> saying regarding this miracle (of The Prophet) that: thirst never
> overcome me after sucking The Prophet’s tongue (as his grandfather)…
>
> مناقب الامام امیرالمومنین علی بن ابی طالب علیه السلام ، از محمد بن
> سلیمان کوفی، ص 232، ح 698.

Accordingly, it could be counted as an accepted hadith as a miracle of the apostle of Allah (peace be upon him and his family).
Even there is another similar narration which has narrated concerning Imam Hussein (a.s.) which has mentioned in short as below

> … Imam Hussein (a.s.) didn’t lactate, since his mother’s (Hazrat
> Fatimah-a-Zahra) breast milk was dry; So, Ibn Shahr Ashub quoted that
> … then The Prophet (pbuh) came, and put his finger in Hussein’s mouth,
> and he was sucking the Prophet’s finger. Moreover it has narrated
> that the apostle of Allah put his tongue in Hussein’s mouth (feeding…)
> …

**Conclusion:**

It can be considered as an acceptable matter by noting it as A MIRACLE OF THE PROPHET (pbuh) that Prophet Muhammad put his tongue in his grandson in order to feed him… , not as what is said somehow else.

---

References:

- [www.yjc.ir](http://www.yjc.ir/fa/news/5077361/%D9%88%D8%B5%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%B9-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B8%D8%A7%D8%AA%E2%80%8C-%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1)
- [www.ashoora.ir](http://www.ashoora.ir/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86-%D8%B9/article/805.html)
- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread34836.html)

Comment: yeah I agree with you one should accept otherwise should not use such words regarding hadith jazakAllah