# Did our beloved Prophet Muhammad (saw) kiss Hassan & Husein, is this Hadith authentic?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation

I found this hadith online and wanted to know if its authentic?

Hadith Number 16245, Volume Title: “The Sayings of the Syrians,” Chapter Title: “Hadith of Mu’awiya Ibn Abu Sufyan”:

“I saw the prophet – pbuh – sucking on the tongue or the lips of Al-Hassan son of Ali, may the prayers of Allah be upon him. For no tongue or lips that the prophet sucked on will be tormented (by hell fire)

He (the Prophet) lift up his (al Hassan’s) shirt and kissed his (little) penis..”
روى أنه صلى الله عليه و سلم قبل زبيبة الحسن أو الحسين
He (the prophet) kissed the (little) penis of al Hassan or al Husein
رأيت النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم فرج ما بين فخذي الحسين و قبل زبيبته
He (the prophet) put Husein’s legs apart and kissed his (little) penis

Another Hadith. Majma al-Zawa’id, Ali ibn Abu Bakr al-Haythami, 299/9 مجمع الزوائد لعلي بن أبى بكر الهيثمي

رأيت رسول الله صلى الله عليه و سلم فرج ما بين فخذي الحسين و قبل زبيبته
رواه الطبراني و إسناده حسن
translated into English: “I saw the Messenger of Allah pbuh putting Husein’s legs apart and kissing his (little) penis.”

Comment: Related posts: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17867/is-the-hadith-about-the-prophet-sucking-on-the-tongue-true, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27567/hadith-about-the-prophet-and-his-daughter-fatimah-tongue-suckling.

Comment: The hadith is not authentic. See: [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/310392) (Arabic).

Answer (score -1):

It is completely false! How could that be a true narration, from the mouths of those taught by the companions and the Prophet SAW himself? This isn't lawful in Islam, not at all! Allah, and the representation of Allah's Will (Muhammad SAW) would never speak as such, or commit such obscenity. These are the fake words of those who wish to turn others against Islam. Repent to Allah for doubting His Purity and relieve this wretchedness from your mind, brother.